# Normalize function

Tags: python, normalize

To normalize, would this work?:

```
def normalize(arr, axis):
    x = [i for i in range(len(arr.shape))]
    a = x[0]
    x[0] = x[axis]
    x[axis] = a
    arr = arr.transpose(x)
    return (arr/np.sum(arr**2, axis=0)**0.5).transpose(tuple(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `x = x / sum(x)` if you want to normalize. This works on numpy arrays:

```
import numpy

x = [1, 2, 3]
x = numpy.array(x)
x = x / sum(x)
```